# Can someone show me what's wrong with my Redux state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, mern

**EDIT**

The component that state is not rendering in is called TournamentShow, which calls the state and whatever functions I need to use for the Show page.

Nested within it is a conditional to call one of 3 pages, based on

`Tournament.Status === "Open"`,

`Tournament.Status === "Closed"`, and

`Tournament.Status === "Complete"`

*Tournament Show:*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { SignUpPage, HostUI, StartBracket, Results } from './TournamentScreens';
import {
    showTournament,
    addParticipant,
    closeTournament,
    shuffleParticipants
} from '../../actions/tournamentActions';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Spinner } from 'reactstrap';

class TournamentShow extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onSignUp = this.onSignUp.bind(this);
        this.onStartTournament = this.onStartTournament.bind(this);
        this.onShuffleParticipants = this.onShuffleParticipants.bind(this);
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        const id = this.props.match.params.id;
        this.props.showTournament(id);
    };

    static propTypes = {
        tournament: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };

    onSignUp(tournamentId, user) {
        this.props.addParticipant(tournamentId, user);
    };

    onShuffleParticipants(array) {
        let currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;   
        while(0 !== currentIndex) {
            randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
            currentIndex -= 1;  
            temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
            array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
            array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
        }   
        return array;
    };

    onStartTournament(tourneyId) {
        const { participants } = this.props.tournament.showTournament;

        // Randomize participants
        let reorderedParticipants = [];
        const shuffledParticipants = this.onShuffleParticipants(participants);
        shuffledParticipants.forEach(participant => {
            reorderedParticipants.push(participant);
        });

        // Send new participants list to backend
        this.props.shuffleParticipants(tourneyId, reorderedParticipants);

        // Set Status to "Closed"
        this.props.closeTournament(tourneyId);
    };

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.tournament)
        const loading = this.props.tournament.loading || !this.props.tournament.showTournament;

        if(loading) {
            return <Spinner color="light" /> 
        } else {
            if(this.props.tournament.showTournament.status === "Complete") {
                return (
                    <Results />
                );
            } else if(this.props.tournament.showTournament.status === "Closed") {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <HostUI
                            tournament={this.props.tournament.showTournament}
                        />
                        <StartBracket
                            tournament={this.props.tournament.showTournament}
                        />
                    </div>
                );
            } else {
                return (
                    <SignUpPage
                        tournament={this.props.tournament.showTournament}
                        auth={this.props.auth}
                        onSignUp={this.onSignUp}
                        onStartTournament={this.onStartTournament}
                    />
                );
            }
        };
    };
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    tournament: state.tournament,
    auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, 
    { showTournament, addParticipant, closeTournament, shuffleParticipants }
)(TournamentShow);
```

*Tournament Show Screens:*

```
import React from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import { TournamentSignUp, StartTournament } from './resources/buttons';
import { TournamentRules } from './resources/rulesets';
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


// Status === "Open"
export const SignUpPage = ({ tournament, auth, onSignUp, onStartTournament }) => {
};


// Status === "Closed"
export const HostUI = ({ tournament }) => {
    const { players } = tournament.bracket;

    return (
        <div style={{color:"lightgrey"}}>
            <h1>Host UI</h1>
            {
                players && players.map(player => (
                    <div>
                        {player.username}
                    </div>
                ))
            }
        </div>
    );
};


export const StartBracket = ({ tournament }) => {
    const { title, hostedBy, participants } = tournament;

  return (
    <div className="text-center" style={{color:"lightgrey", backgroundColor: "#333333"}}>
      <h1>{ title }</h1>
      <h4>By { hostedBy }</h4>
      <h4>{participants && participants.length}-player bracket</h4>
      <br /><Link to="/">Back to Tournaments main page</Link>
    </div>
  );
};


// Status === "Complete"
export const Results = () => {
};
```

`Status===Closed` shows both of those central components.

`HostUI` renders just the `players` array (which had just been updated right before the status switch/re-render)

`StartBracket` shows stuff from `ShowTournament`, which is all data that had already been set in the state

**ORIGINAL** --------------------------

I'll mark with // comment which case does not work

```
import { 
    GET_TOURNAMENTS, 
    SHOW_TOURNAMENT, 
    ADD_TOURNAMENT,
    ADD_TOURNAMENT_FAIL,
    EDIT_TOURNAMENT,
    EDIT_TOURNAMENT_FAIL,
    DELETE_TOURNAMENT, 
    TOURNAMENTS_LOADING, 
    TOURNAMENT_LOADING,
    USER_JOINS_TOURNAMENT, 
    TOURNAMENT_SIGN_UP_FAIL,
    TOURNAMENT_STATUS_UPDATE,
    TOURNAMENT_STATUS_FAILED,
    SHUFFLE_PARTICIPANTS,
    SHUFFLE_FAILED
} from '../actions/types';


const initialState = {
    tournaments: [],
    showTournament: {},
    loading: false,
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case GET_TOURNAMENTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                tournaments: action.payload,
                loading: false
            };

        case SHOW_TOURNAMENT:
            return {
                ...state,
                showTournament: action.payload,
                loading: false
            };

        case ADD_TOURNAMENT:
            return {
                ...state,
                tournaments: [action.payload, ...state.tournaments]
            };

        case DELETE_TOURNAMENT:
            return {
                ...state,
                tournaments: state.tournaments.filter(tournament => tournament._id !== action.payload)
            };

        case TOURNAMENTS_LOADING:
        case TOURNAMENT_LOADING:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            };

        case USER_JOINS_TOURNAMENT:
            return {
                ...state,
                ...state.showTournament.participants.push(action.payload)
            };

        case TOURNAMENT_STATUS_UPDATE:      // Occurs with SHUFFLE_PARTICIPANTS, which doesn't work
            return {
                ...state,
                ...state.showTournament.status = action.payload
            };

        case SHUFFLE_PARTICIPANTS:          // Does not work
            return {
                ...state,
                ...state.showTournament.bracket.players.push(action.payload)
            }

        case EDIT_TOURNAMENT:
        case ADD_TOURNAMENT_FAIL:
        case EDIT_TOURNAMENT_FAIL:
        case TOURNAMENT_SIGN_UP_FAIL:
        case TOURNAMENT_STATUS_FAILED:
        case SHUFFLE_FAILED:
            return {
                ...state,
            }

        default:
            return state;
    };
};
```

Most of that works.
The ones I'm sure I screwed up are `TOURNAMENT_STATUS_UPDATE` and `SHUFFLE_PARTICIPANTS`, although status update works as intended.

This is a tournament app whose show page renders 3 different components based on `showTournament.status`

```
...

    if(loading) {
        return <Spinner color="light" /> 
    } else {
        if(this.props.tournament.showTournament.status === "Complete") {
            return (
                <Results />
            );
        } else if(this.props.tournament.showTournament.status === "Closed") {
            return (
                <div>
                    <HostUI
                        tournament={this.props.tournament.showTournament}
                    />
                    <StartBracket
                        tournament={this.props.tournament.showTournament}
                    />
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <SignUpPage
                    tournament={this.props.tournament.showTournament}
                    auth={this.props.auth}
                    onSignUp={this.onSignUp}
                    onStartTournament={this.onStartTournament}
                />
            );
        }
    };
```

Component button:

- randomizes `Tournament.participants` and sends it to `Tournament.bracket.players`
- sets `Tournament.status === "Closed"`

That updates the page and renders the `Status: "Closed"` page correctly.

The problem is, it only displays whatever I already had loaded in the state. (stuff from `SHOW_TOURNAMENT`)

The `bracket.players` array I sent the randomized user list to doesn't display until I refresh the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to shallow copy each level of state you are updating. Also, `...state.showTournament.bracket.players.push(action.payload)` will simply attempt to spread in the return value of the `push` which is just the new length of the array. This isn't what you want.

```
case TOURNAMENT_STATUS_UPDATE:
  return {
    ...state,
    showTournament: {
      ...state.showTournament,
      status: action.payload,
    },
  };

case SHUFFLE_PARTICIPANTS:
  return {
    ...state,
    showTournament: {
      ...state.showTournament,
      bracket: {
        ...state.showTournatment.bracket,
        players: [...state.showTournament.bracket.players, ...action.payload], // spread payload array
      },
    },
  }
```

Comment: I read that on the docs but it didn't sink in. Okay, I just tried that.
Same thing.  Component updates and shows the next page (as per Status) but I still need to refresh to get the players rendered

Comment: @Cin88 What component is the state not updating in? Can you include that component code and how it is connected to your redux store?

Comment: Thanks Drew.  Updated the post to answer your question

Comment: @Cin88 Have you verified your actions are hitting redux and the reducer? Do you have the redux-devtools installed to verify the state is updated to what you expect it to be? If you implement a `componentDidUpdate` function do you see the updated props there?

Comment: I do have the devtools installed.  Just saw something interesting.
When the component renders, it's showing `players` as an array of an array, rather than it being an array of objects.

However when I refresh, it becomes just an array of objects.

As for componentDidUpdate I honestly don't know how to use that method, so none of my components have that (except for some auth components I learned from youtube guides)

Comment: I think that solution works initially for sending one element to an array.  In this case, I'm pushing an array's elements into another array.  I think I got it

Comment: Figured it out.  Your solution actually did work, it got Redux to update properly, but since I was passing an array I had to do [...action.payload].  Thanks! Will upvote and check off your answer.  Much appreciated

Comment: @Cin88 Great! I amended my answer as well. Cheers. `componentDidUpdate` is just a lifecycle function called when state or props update, it's an easy place to just drop a console log for anything you want to check when the component re-renders.

Answer (score 0):

Drew's solution worked, it was just that, in order to pass an array into another array, the syntax is

`players: [...state.showTournament.bracket.players. ...action.payload]`

rather than `players: [...state.showTournament.bracket.players, action.payload]`

Good day